# MySQL5.1 Query with join and count

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have this following query:

```
select teams.`team_name`, count(matches.`played_team`) 
from teams 
join matches on teams.`team_number` = matches.`played_team` 
group by teams.`team_name`
```

It is used to show the team name, team number and the amount of matches they have played.
I wish to add a WHERE clause to this query which only counts the number of games played past 2011-01-01. `matches.date` holds info on the dates of the games.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by you want to "add a WHERE clause"? I ask because I assume you *have* actually tried adding a where clause, right? And I assume that it didn't give you the results you wanted? Could you show what you tried and why it doesn't give you the result you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select teams.`team_name`, count(matches.`played_team`) 
from teams 
join matches on teams.`team_number` = matches.`played_team`
WHERE `matches.date` > '2011-01-01' 
group by teams.`team_name`
```